# What should be react default prop type for PropTypes.shape?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Say I have the following condition:

```
    static propTypes = {
        deployment: PropTypes.shape({
            getMetrics: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            getRootMetric: PropTypes.func.isRequired
       }).isRequired,
}
```

How would I declare the `default` for deployment ? Would it be undefined or would it be [] ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the prop is required, I see no reason to define a default. Defaults are only useful for optional props which also have a reasonable default value, such as an empty list `[]` or an empty object `{}`.

Answer (score 2):

You could not define a default prop or you could just say `{getMetrics: () => {}, getRootMetric: () => {}}` since it's an object. However, `required` props don't really need defaults, otherwise they wouldn't really be required.

To give an example :
You build a small npm module that comes along with a `config` object

- You can define this object as required (the module would break
  without users providing it)
- You can provide defaults (it would work with these if not provided)

So, finally, it's up to you *if* and *how* you provide defaults.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like the below:

```
SomeComponent.defaultProps = {
  deployment: {
    getMetrics: () => {},
    getRootMetric: () => {}
  }
}
```

Defaults are good when not having the values would break your app.